# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Tags: model-view-controller, consumer

The code in consumer side is:

```
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://IP ADDRESS:5000/api/");

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CategoriesController()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        
        List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();

        HttpResponseMessage response = 
            await _httpClient.GetAsync(_httpClient.BaseAddress + "categories");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            categories = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Category>>(data);
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

I created an API in .net8, and I setup the CORS for any request, region and header. The "applicationUrl" inside the "launchSettings.json" is set to
`"applicationUrl": "https://IP ADDRESS:5000;http://IP ADDRESS:5001"` in the "https".

But in consuming app which is created by MVC .net core8, once requesting, I got two error as follow:

> AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
>
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)